# SpringBoot throws NoClassDefFoundError at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, noclassdeffounderror

We use SpringBoot 1.4.7 web to deploy ActiveMq 5.13.5 broker. The build artifact is a jar file which is launched by java command. Most of the time, it runs smoothly without any problem. However, without restarting the app, it randomly throws the following exception once or twice a day:

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected error occurred: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQTextMessage
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQTextMessage
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v11.ActiveMQTextMessageMarshaller.createObject(ActiveMQTextMessageMarshaller.java:55)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.doUnmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:360)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:277)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

I ensured the class ActiveMQTextMessage had been loaded before the exception time by outputting the class loading debug. I also ensured the system has plenty of free capacity for the cpu, memory(heap and meta), disk, file handles and sockets.

I have a few questions here:

1. Anyone saw similar problem and know the cause and fix?
2. Does SpringBoot unload class at runtime and reload them back?
3. Any hint to further debug this type of problem is highly appreciated.

   **Edit:**
   The dependency tree for compile and runtime is posted here: https://gist.github.com/liuzy163/8b8f8c7119624b5bdbe30e133d5f5910

Comment: can you please post your dependency tree?

Comment: Thanks @bestwishes,  I edited the question with the dependency tree appended.

Comment: does it always happen  while running from same location or randomly occurs? did you try running it from some other location? any pattern in the randomness?

Comment: The jar is deployed to two linux servers and both have same problem. It happens once or twice a day in unpredictable manner. After restarting the process, it would happily run for a long while then suddenly entered this weird condition.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm getting exactly same situation. Very uncomfortable situation.